# Python equivalent of free() for numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, memory-leaks, dask

I have a number of large `numpy` arrays that need to be stored as `dask` arrays. While trying to load each array from `.npy` and then convert it into `dask.array`, I noticed the RAM usage was almost just as much as regular `numpy` arrays even after I `del arr` after loading `arr` into `dask.array`.

In this example:

```
arr = np.random.random((100, 300))
print(f'Array ref count before conversion: {sys.getrefcount(arr) - 1}') # output: 1
dask_arr = da.from_array(arr)
print(f'Distributed array ref count: {sys.getrefcount(dask_arr) - 1}') # output: 1
print(f'Array ref count after conversion: {sys.getrefcount(arr) - 1}') # output: 3
```

My only guess is that while `dask` was loading the array, it created references to the `numpy` array.

How can I free up the memory and delete all references to the memory location (like free(ptr) in C)?

Comment: give it a shot after you write to diskarray  `import gc; gc.collect()`

Comment: Python *doesn't expose any way to manage memory explicitly*

Comment: @Ehsan important to note, `gc` only affects the cyclic garbage collector

Comment: @Ehsan, I [tried](https://imgur.com/1WA81pW) `gc` but that did not work. The memory was still not freed.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Interesting point. Thank you for the note.

Comment: have you tried using 'del' on your objects and then calling the gc?

Comment: @yann, yes, please check my above comment where I attached a screenshot

Comment: Nothing prevent Dask from referencing the Numpy array. This would be a perfectly valid behavior.

Comment: @yannziselman `del` does not free memory and `gc` is only the supplemental garbage collector that is in charge of clearing unreachable reference cycles that escape the main garbage collection strategy, reference counting,

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a `MemoryError` you may have a few options:

- Break your data into smaller chunks.
- Manually trigger garbage collection and/or tweak the gc settings on the workers through a Worker Plugin (which op has tried but doesn't work; I'll include anyway for other readers)
- Trim memory using `malloc_trim` (esp. if working with non-NumPy data or small NumPy chunks)
- Make sure you can see [the Dask Dashboard](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/best-practices.html?highlight=dashboard#use-the-dashboard) while your computations are running to figure out which approach is working.

From [this resource](https://coiled.io/blog/tackling-unmanaged-memory-with-dask/):

"Another important cause of unmanaged memory on Linux and MacOSX, which is not widely known about, derives from the fact that the `libc malloc()/free()` manage a user-space memory pool, so `free()` won’t necessarily release memory back to the OS."